# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

So I developed a simple CRUD program from the tutorial video of backbonejs.org and the code worked fine. Now I'm trying to implement the code in requirejs but it shows following error in the following code: -

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'router',
'models/Customers/Customer',
'helper/Serialize'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Customer, Serialize) {

    var CustomerEditView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '.page',
        events: {
            'submit .edit-customer-form': 'saveCustomer',
            'click .delete': 'deleteCustomer',

        },

        saveCustomer: function (ev) {
            var customerDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
            var customer = new Customer();
            customer.save(customerDetails, {
                success: function (customer) {
                    this.router.navigate('', { trigger: true });
                }
            });
            return false;
        },
```

Comment: Please *[edit] the question* to state the exact error message (including line number that matches the line number in the code as pasted in the question, you probably also want to restate an exact copy of that line so we know for sure which one it is).  This information needs to be *in the question*, not just a comment. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'll go through these suggestions.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
customer.save(customerDetails, {
                success: function (customer) {
                    Backbone.history.navigate('', { trigger: true });
                }
```

if you want to use router object first you have to initialize it like

```
this.router  = new router();
```

and you can say  `this.router.navigate('', { trigger: true });`

it is not optimal to create a new instance in all the views and not suggested to make the object global. `You can use Backbone.history.nvaigate which is alias to router.nvaigate`

Comment: Using `Backbone.history.navigate` instead of `this.router.navigate` solved my problem too. Thanks!